# Search and replace with Regex with replace variables

Tags: regex

My company is using a third party for their mobile sites and we have a console to update some of the code and control stuff through them. One of the things is a search and replace feature that can update the code for the site. The only thing is: it uses a lot of complex regex code and I can't seem to find a good tutorial on the complex stuff. So here is the example he gave me that sticks grabs the paragraph tag and puts it in the link:

**Search**

```
(#d6d6d4.+?>.+?<p><a.+?>.+?)</a>(.+?)</td>
```

**Replace With**

```
$1$2</a></td>
```

What is the `$1` and `$2` representing? I know it probably has something to do with one of the `.+?` but I am unsure which one. I have added the code down below with numbers next to the regex variables

```
(#d6d6d4.+?**[1]**>.+?**[2]**<p><a.+?**[3]**>.+?**[4]**)</a>(.+?**[5]**)</td>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The $1 and $2 represent the text in capturing groups in the regex. Capturing groups are what is inside parentheses.

```
 (        // start first capture group
 #d6d6d4  // match #d6d6d4
 .+?>     // any character, non-greedy, up to '>'
 .+?<p>   // any character, non-greedy, up to <p>
 <a.+?>   // an <a..> tag, consuming everything up to '>'
 .+?      // all characters from <a> to </a>
 )        // close the first capture group before the '</a>'
 </a>     // literal '</a>' 
 (        // start second capture group
 .+?      // match all, non-greedy up to '</td>'
 )        // close capture group before '</td>'
 </td>    // literal '</td>'
```

So you if you have this string: `<td color=#d6d6d4 foo=bar>Hello, world<p><a href=http://foo.com>foo link</a>some more text</td>`

$1 matches: `#d6d6d4 foo=bar>Hello, world<p><a href=http://foo.com>foo link`
$2 matches: `some more text`

So the string is transformed into:
`<td color=#d6d6d4 foo=bar>Hello, world<p><a href=http://foo.com>foo linksome more text</a></td>`

Which basically means the `</a>` tag is moved after `some more text` (or just before the `</td>` if you prefer)

Answer (score 5):

The `$1` and `$2` variables are captured matches for the patterns inside parentheses, i.e. `()`.

`$1` is the first capturing group and `$2` the second.

Answer (score 2):

I consider http://rubular.com/ to be a great training tool for regex's because it's interactive and you can keep trying different patterns against different text and you see the results immediately.

It includes a link to http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UJ which is a good basic guide to regular expressions.

There's also http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Why struggle to write your own when there's even a site for 3,500+ regex libraries at http://regexlib.com

The $ variables are used to store 'the match's that are made:- $1 for the first match; $2 for the second, etc.

Comment: Ok i see where $2 is getting populated there at the end but where is $1 getting the info