# How can I append something to a string using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have a bunch of code with lines like these spread all over:

```
plt.savefig( 'fig1.png' )
...
plt.savefig( 'figblah.png' )
```

I want to change every line to be:

```
plt.savefig( 'fig1.png', dpi=300  )
...
plt.savefig( 'figblah.png', dpi=300 )
```

I am very unexperienced with regex and been trying for a while with no success. I browsed lots of questions here, but just won't work yet. So far, I can find the strings with: `(?=savefig).*`, but I'm stuck there. I fancy that the problem is somehow *get the found value* and append the ', dpi=300
 string, but don't know how to do that.

(I'm working in jupyter-notebook, if that makes a difference)

Comment: @baddger964 Jupyter comes with a find and replace dialog, I'm playing with it now

Comment: @baddger964: Of course one can replace with regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your limited examples, it looks like replacing `)` with `, dpi=300)` would suffice. If you need to capture the `savefig`, something like `(savefig\([^)]+)\)` and replacing with `$1, dpi=300)` should work.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways, one being with a **positive lookbehind**:

```
(?<=plt\.savefig) # positive lookbehind for plt.savefig
\(                # match an opening parenthesis
([^)]+)           # capture anything not a )
\)                # match a closing parenthesis
```

This needs to be replaced with `(\1, dpi=300)`, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/uV6iN6/1).

Comment: Jupyter doesn't even find `(?<=plt\.savefig)` or `(?<=plt.savefig)`. Could it be platform-dependent?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059129/search-and-replace-with-regex-with-replace-variables) I found out about ***capture groups*** and found a solution myself:

Search for: `(savefig.*\ )`

Replace with: `$1, dpi=300`